# Non analytic, non constant , continuous complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, analytic-functions

I am trying to construct a non analytic , non constant, continuous function $f $ such that $f$ :$ \mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\to  \mathbb C$ with $f(z)= f\left(\frac{z}{|z|}\right)$.
I got stuck how to start this problem

Answer (score 1):

How about $f(z)=z/|z|$? This is continuous on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, not analytic since $|z|$ is involved, non constant and we have $f(z/|z|)=(z/|z|)/|z/|z||=(z/|z|)/1=z/|z|=f(z)$

Comment: i want to know the points where f is not analytic except zero

Comment: @PrashantDattatrey Well, check for yourself. for $h\in\mathbb{R}^+$, compute $[f(z+h)-f(z)]/h$ and take the limit as $h\to0^+$. Compute also $[f(z+ih)-f(z)]/(ih)$ and take the limit as$h\to0^+$. Are these two equal?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the condition of non-constant is trivial for any non-analytic $f$.

Using polar coordinates $z=r.e^{i\theta}$

$f(r.e^{i\theta})=f(\frac{r.e^{i\theta}}{|r.e^{i\theta}|})$

$f(r.e^{i\theta})=f(e^{i\theta})$

A convenient choice will be $f(r.e^{i\theta})=\theta^2\implies f(z)=(Arg(z))^2$ which is defined on $\mathbb C/{0}$.

Comment: $ f(z) = arg (z)$ is not continuous on $\Bbb C\setminus0$ unless you delete a ray (originating from origin) from complex plane

Comment: You are right. I fixed that now.

Comment: This Arg (Z) should be principal argument

Comment: yes it is. There is big A.